# Error when compiling Jasper Reports using Jasper Reports API 6.13.0 with Adopt OpenJDK 11

Tags: java, jasper-reports, openjdk-11, adoptopenjdk

we have a utility (CompileJasperReports.jar) that we use to compile all reports found in a folder

When using JasperReports 6.7 API with Java 8 the utility runs fine. The call is

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java" -jar CompileJasperReports.jar <in-folder containing .jrxml files> <out-folder for .jasper files>

These are the jars that are used by the CompileJasperReports.jar

- jasperreports-6.7.0.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
- commons-digester-2.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.2.jar

Now we are trying to migrate to JasperReports 6.13.0 API and Java 11.

The utility is compiled with Java 11 and the call to it is

"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.8.10-hotspot\bin\java" -jar --add-opens java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util=ALL-UNNAMED CompileJasperReports.jar <in-folder containing .jrxml files> <out-folder for .jasper files>

These are the jars that are used by the CompileJasperReports.jar

- jasperreports-6.13.0.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar
- commons-collections4-4.4.jar
- commons-digester-2.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.2.jar

Most of the reports are compiled without problems, but for some the following error occurs:

Compiling master_report.jrxml to master_report.jasper...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.deleteSourceFiles(JRAbstractCompiler.java:407)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:281)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:358)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:274)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:256)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:555)
at com.ietsol.enterprise.CompileJasperReports.main(CompileJasperReports.java:24)
```

The main code of the utility is

```
private static final String defExtension = ".jrxml";
private static final String compExtension = ".jasper";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (!checkArguments(args)) 
        return;
    
    File inputDir = new File(args[0]);
    File[] files = inputDir.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.endsWith(defExtension));
    for (File reportDef : files) {
        String defFileName = reportDef.getName();
        String compFileName = defFileName.replace(defExtension, compExtension);
        System.out.println("Compiling " + defFileName + " to " + compFileName + "...");
        try {
            JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(args[0] + File.separator + defFileName, args[1] + File.separator + compFileName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
```

Any hints are highly welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in JasperReports 6.13.0.

One way to workaround the bug is to include a JDT/ECJ compiler jar in your application.  JasperReports 6.13.0 lists ECJ 3.21.0 as dependency, you can get it [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt/ecj).

An alternative workaround is to add the following property to jasperreports.properties, if you have one in your application:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.legacy.compiler.source.included.parameters=REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP
```

You can also set the property programmatically if you don't have/want a jasperreports.properties file:

```
    DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance().setProperty(
            ReportSourceCompilation.PROPERTY_LEGACY_SOURCE_INCLUDED_PARAMETERS, 
            JRParameter.REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP);
```