# JasperReport cannot find symbol JREvaluator in WildFly, works without server

Tags: java, jboss, jasper-reports, wildfly

Recently I've been working on report generation with Jasper. I have created a simple program to test it and when running it via IDE it did work fine.

Then I moved the (very short) class to WildFly sever application and despite having the exact same code and library generation fails with `cannot find symbol`. Those symbols it cannot find are `JREvaluator`, `JRFillVariable` as well as packages such as `net.sf.jasperreports.engine`

In so far I have confirmed that:

- Project builds (meaning those classes are visible for javac, but not jvm)
- `jasperreports-6.13.0.jar` is added to `war` (it's present in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder alongside other libraries, like `gson` and `hibernate`
- `jasperreports-6.13.0.jar` contains the missing classes

It looks to me like the problem doesn't lie in library not being loaded or missing classes (because in testing environment it works), but like something was preventing JBoss class loader from loading those classes

**Attempted (and failed) solutions**

- Clean and Build
- Adding `-Djava.awt.headless=true` to VM options - this did not changed anything
- Adding `-Djava.awt.headless=false` to VM options - also didn't change a thing, but once caused `NullPointerException` inside `jasperreport` library. For testing program - worked in both cases
- Adding `commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar`, `commons-digester-2.1.jar`, `commons-collections4-4.4.jar` and `commons-loggin-1.2.jar` - with no changes
- Adding `jasper-compiler-jdt-5.5.23.jar` - this caused a different error, namely `NoSuchMethodError` for `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ICompilerRequestor` and few others. This library however should not be necessary as - from what I understand - `jasperreport-6.13.0.jar` already contains it's compiler and separate library for compiler is not required since a long time.

**What has not been attempted:**

- Forcing the classes to load (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/Forcethegivenclasstobeloadedfully.htm)
- Dynamically loading jar during Runtime or using custom class loader

**Update:** after looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63072294/4903564) answer and applying the suggestion the missing class was different. Which suggests that the dependencies **inside** `jasperreport.jar` are not being loaded properly

Comment: **cannot find symbol** is a compilation failure.This means that the classes JREvaluator, JRFillVariable and the package net.sf.jasperreports.engine have not been imported in the code,before referencing them.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out

For some reason in server project libraries used by jasperreport.jar were not loaded, but in the testing project they were (might be due to WildFly, might be due to differences between IntelliJ and NetBeans)

Here is the list of libraries, based on `pom.xml` file in jasperreport.jar that I have added. Some might not be necessary and the list might not be exhaustive (I basically stopped adding libraries once report started generating) but it's good enough base if someone else runs into this problem:

- `commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar`
- `itext-2.1.7.jar`
- `poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar`
- `commons-collections4-4.4.jar`
- `jcommon-1.0.23.jar`
- `xalan-2.7.2.jar`
- `commons-digester-2.1.jar`
- `jfreechart-1.0.19.jar`
- `xmpcore-5.1.3.jar`
- `commons-logging-1.2.jar`
- `poi-4.1.1.jar`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my project execute (by jasper library) a Jasper Report.

On my IDE and JBoss server a did not haver problem, but when I deployed over WildFly the problem appears.

I just needed to add **jasper-compiler-jdt.jar** to the project libraries, and finally works on WildFly.